# Pandas to_sql - The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) prototcol stream is incorrect

Tags: python, pandas, azure, sqlalchemy, databricks

I'm trying to write a Pandas dataframe (filtered_df) to an Azure SQL database in Azure Databricks using the to_sql function and a sqlalchemy engine:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER={0};PORT=1433;DATABASE={1};UID={2};PWD={3};TDS_Version=8.0;".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcDatabase, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword))))
filtered_df.to_sql("[myschema].[my_table]", con=engine, index=False, if_exists="append", schema='myschema')
```

But, I'm getting the following error:

```
(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 7 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision. (8023) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I've checked my dataframe and it has the same structure as my SQL table. It refers to a **"Parameter 7 ("")"** but none of my dataframe entries have the value "" (empty string). I'm not sure what else it could be referring to, but how to I find out what I need to change about my dataframe?

## Update

As per GordThompson's comment below, the following Stack Overflow post contains a solution to this issue: [How to solve error in Pandas for "The incoming tabular data stream in remote procedure call protocal stream is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60157330/2144390)

The problem was that my data frame had infinite values in, which could not be written to SQL.

Comment: Side note: Neither `PORT=` nor `TDS_Version=` are valid for Microsoft's ODBC drivers for SQL Server. Omit them from your connection string.

Comment: Thanks will update that.

Comment: @GordThompson Any advice on the actual question though? :) Do you know how I can check what values the are that are causing the issues?

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60157330/2144390

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson. That solved my issue!